# Terrarium code in Eloquent Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

This is a code from the book Eloquent Javascript. It creates a 2D object called Terrarium where in insects can move. Insects are moved using the function:terrarium.step . But when I run it says 'center is undefined'. center is the argument of a function:Terrarium.prototype.listSurroundings. This function calls another function which uses a method of center as an argument. What could be wrong? I am attaching the whole code here including initialisation of terrarium etc.

```
function forEach(array,action) {
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {action(array[i]);}
}

function forEachIn(object, action) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property))
        action(property, object[property]);
    }
}

function Dictionary(startValues) {
    this.values = startValues || {};
}
Dictionary.prototype.store = function(name, value) {
    this.values[name] = value;
};
Dictionary.prototype.lookup = function(name) {
    return this.values[name];
};

Dictionary.prototype.contains = function(name) {
    return Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(this.values, name);
};
Dictionary.prototype.each = function(action) {
    forEachIn(this.values, action);
};

function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype.add = function(other) {
    return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
};

function Grid(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.cells = new Array(width * height);
}
Grid.prototype.valueAt = function(point) {
    return this.cells[point.y * this.width + point.x];
};
Grid.prototype.setValueAt = function(point, value) {
    this.cells[point.y * this.width + point.x] = value;
};
Grid.prototype.isInside = function(point) {
    return point.x >= 0 && point.y >= 0 &&
    point.x < this.width && point.y < this.height;
};
Grid.prototype.moveValue = function(from, to) {
    this.setValueAt(to, this.valueAt(from));
    this.setValueAt(from, undefined);
};

Grid.prototype.each = function(action) {
    for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
            var point = new Point(x, y);
            action(point, this.valueAt(point));
        }
    }
};

var directions = new Dictionary(
{"n": new Point( 0, -1),
 "ne": new Point( 1, -1),
 "e": new Point( 1, 0),
 "se": new Point( 1, 1),
 "s": new Point( 0, 1),
 "sw": new Point(-1, 1),
 "w": new Point(-1, 0),
 "nw": new Point(-1, -1)});

function StupidBug() {};
StupidBug.prototype.act = function(surroundings) {
    return {type: "move", direction: "s"};
};

var wall = {};

function elementFromCharacter(character) {
    if (character == " ")
        return undefined;
    else if (character == "#")
        return wall;
    else if (character == "o")
        return new StupidBug();
}

function Terrarium(plan) {
    var grid = new Grid(plan[0].length, plan.length);
    for (var y = 0; y < plan.length; y++) {
        var line = plan[y];
        for (var x = 0; x < line.length; x++) {
            grid.setValueAt(new Point(x, y), elementFromCharacter(line.charAt(x)));
        }
    }
    this.grid = grid;
}

wall.character = "#";
StupidBug.prototype.character = "o";
function characterFromElement(element) {
    if (element == undefined)
        return " ";
    else
    return element.character;
}

Terrarium.prototype.toString = function() {
    var characters = [];
    var endOfLine = this.grid.width - 1;
    this.grid.each(function(point, value) {
        characters.push(characterFromElement(value));
        if (point.x == endOfLine)
        characters.push("\n");
    });
    return characters.join("");
};

function bind(func, object) {
    return function(){
        return func.apply(object, arguments);
    };
}

function method(object, name) {
    return function() {
        object[name].apply(object, arguments);
    };
}

Terrarium.prototype.listActingCreatures = function() {
    var found = [];
    this.grid.each(function(point, value) {
        if (value != undefined && value.act)
        found.push({object: value, point: point});
    });
    return found;
};

Terrarium.prototype.listSurroundings = function(center) {
    var result = {};
    var grid = this.grid;
    directions.each(function(name, direction) {
        var place = center.add(direction);
        if (grid.isInside(place))
        result[name] = characterFromElement(grid.valueAt(place));
        else result[name] = "#";
    });
    return result;
};

Terrarium.prototype.processCreature = function(creature, point) {
    var action = creature.act(this.listSurroundings(point));
    if (action.type == "move" && directions.contains(action.direction)) {
        var to = point.add(directions.lookup(action.direction));
        if (this.grid.isInside(to) && this.grid.valueAt(to) == undefined)
            this.grid.moveValue(point, to);
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Unsupported action: " + action.type);
    }
};

Terrarium.prototype.step = function() {
    forEach(this.listActingCreatures(), bind(this.processCreature, this));
};

var thePlan =
["############################",
 "#      #    #      o      ##",
 "#                          #",
 "#          #####           #",
 "##         #   #    ##     #",
 "###           ##     #     #",
 "#           ###      #     #",
 "#  ####                    #",
 "#  ##        o             #",
 "# o #          o       ### #",
 "#   #                      #",
 "############################"]
var terrarium = new Terrarium(thePlan);
terrarium.step();
alert(terrarium);
```

Comment: Thanks gthacoder for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your processCreature method a little bit:

```
Terrarium.prototype.processCreature = function(creature) {
  var action = creature.object.act(this.listSurroundings(creature.point));
  if (action.type == "move" && directions.contains(action.direction)) {
    var to = creature.point.add(directions.lookup(action.direction));
    if (this.grid.isInside(to) && this.grid.valueAt(to) == undefined)
      this.grid.moveValue(creature.point, to);
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Unsupported action: " + action.type);
  }
};
```

I executed that in Firefox and it works. I'm not sure if it runs as supposed to, but it alerts something.

Comment: arguments are provided when function is called in:  'forEach(this.listActingCreatures(), bind(this.processCreature, this));'     'this.listActingCreatures()' returns an array of objects each containing creature 'value' and location of the creature. So there is no need to give more arguments there.

Comment: Good point. You are right. My bad. I updated the answer. Now it seems like some working code.

Comment: Yes it works now. I don't get why you wrote:'creature.object.act' instead of 'creature.act'. That makes the code work and does not work with 'creature.act' For me the code is not running as it is supposed but the error lies elsewhere I guess. It is giving some output now.

Comment: It works there is no error in output. I was wrong in the previous comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Full source code here and it's work.

```
// forEachIn
function forEachIn(object, action) {
  for (var property in object) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property))
      action(property, object[property]);
  }
}

// Dictionary type
function Dictionary(startValues) {
  this.values = startValues || {};
}
Dictionary.prototype.store = function(name, value) {
  this.values[name] = value;
};
Dictionary.prototype.lookup = function(name) {
  return this.values[name];
};
Dictionary.prototype.contains = function(name) {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.values, name) &&
    Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(this.values, name);
};
Dictionary.prototype.each = function(action) {
  forEachIn(this.values, action);
};

// terrarium plan
var thePlan = [
  "############################",
  "#      #    #      o      ##",
  "#                          #",
  "#          #####           #",
  "##         #   #    ##     #",
  "###           ##     #     #",
  "#           ###      #     #",
  "#   ####                   #",
  "#   ##       o             #",
  "# o  #         o       ### #",
  "#    #                     #",
  "############################"
];

// Point type
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype.add = function(other) {
  return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
};

// Grid type
function Grid(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.cells = new Array(width * height);
}
Grid.prototype.valueAt = function(point) {
  return this.cells[point.y * this.width + point.x];
};
Grid.prototype.setValueAt = function(point, value) {
  this.cells[point.y * this.width + point.x] = value;
};
Grid.prototype.isInside = function(point) {
  return point.x >= 0 && point.y >= 0 &&
         point.x < this.width && point.y < this.height;
};
Grid.prototype.moveValue = function(from, to) {
  this.setValueAt(to, this.valueAt(from));
  this.setValueAt(from, undefined);
};

Grid.prototype.each = function(action) {
  for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
      var point = new Point(x, y);
      action(point, this.valueAt(point));
    }
  }
};

// directions object
var directions = new Dictionary(
  {"n":  new Point( 0, -1),
   "ne": new Point( 1, -1),
   "e":  new Point( 1,  0),
   "se": new Point( 1,  1),
   "s":  new Point( 0,  1),
   "sw": new Point(-1,  1),
   "w":  new Point(-1,  0),
   "nw": new Point(-1, -1)});

// StupidBug
function StupidBug() {}
StupidBug.prototype.act = function(surroundings) {
  return {type: "move", direction: "s"};
};

// Terrarium
var wall = {};

function elementFromCharacter(character) {
  if (character == " ")
    return undefined;
  else if (character == "#")
    return wall;
  else if (character == "o")
    return new StupidBug();
}

function Terrarium(plan) {
  var grid = new Grid(plan[0].length, plan.length);
  for (var y = 0; y < plan.length; y++) {
    var line = plan[y];
    for (var x = 0; x < line.length; x++) {
      grid.setValueAt(new Point(x, y), elementFromCharacter(line.charAt(x)));
    }
  }
  this.grid = grid;
}

// characterFromElement
wall.character = "#";
StupidBug.prototype.character = "o";

function characterFromElement(element) {
  if (element === undefined)
    return " ";
  else
    return element.character;
}

// Terrarium.prototype.toString
Terrarium.prototype.toString = function() {
  var characters = [];
  var endOfLine = this.grid.width - 1;
  this.grid.each(function(point, value) {
    characters.push(characterFromElement(value));
    if (point.x == endOfLine)
      characters.push("\n");
  });
  return characters.join("");
};

// bind and method
function bind(func, object) {
  return function(){
    return func.apply(object, arguments);
  };
}

function method(object, name) {
  return function() {
    object[name].apply(object, arguments);
  };
}

// Terrarium.prototype.step
Terrarium.prototype.listActingCreatures = function() {
  var found = [];
  this.grid.each(function(point, value) {
    if (value !== undefined && value.act)
      found.push({object: value, point: point});
  });
  return found;
};

Terrarium.prototype.listSurroundings = function(center) {
  var result = {};
  var grid = this.grid;
  directions.each(function(name, direction) {
    var place = center.add(direction);
    if (grid.isInside(place))
      result[name] = characterFromElement(grid.valueAt(place));
    else
      result[name] = "#";
  });
  return result;
};

Terrarium.prototype.processCreature = function(creature) {
  var action = creature.object.act(this.listSurroundings(creature.point));

  if (action.type == "move" && directions.contains(action.direction)) {
    var to = creature.point.add(directions.lookup(action.direction));
    if (this.grid.isInside(to) && this.grid.valueAt(to) === undefined)
      this.grid.moveValue(creature.point, to);
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Unsupported action: " + action.type);
  }
};

Terrarium.prototype.step = function() {
  forEach(this.listActingCreatures(), bind(this.processCreature, this));
};

function forEach(array,action) {
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {action(array[i]);}
}

// Run demo - Check in console
var terrarium = new Terrarium(thePlan);
console.log(terrarium.toString());
terrarium.step();
console.log(terrarium.toString());
```

Check demo here, result in console: https://jsfiddle.net/huyb1991/baoe8qj6/